# Java Spring maxFileSize and maxRequestSize not being honored?

Tags: spring-boot

Intermediate Java skills, new to Spring, I'm going through one of Spring.io's Getting Started Guides: [Uploading Files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/).  Per the guide I'm setting some properties in an `application.properties`

```
multipart.maxFileSize: 128KB
multipart.maxRequestSize: 128KB
server.port = 8090
```

(I'm changing the tomcat port just to verify that this props file is being recognized, and the port is changed to 8090.)  But running `mvn spring-boot:run` and accessing `localhost:8090`, I'm able to upload and subsequently requests/view a 700kb file.  (Rather, I was expecting some application error to prevent both operations.)  I've re-read the guide and googled around but can't figure out if I'm missing some other config to get these limits to be observed by the app.  How do I get the app to observe these limits, or did I have an incorrect expectation from reading the guide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you've encountered happened because of the bug in the sample application. I see that they've upgraded the application to use Spring Boot 1.4 a week ago, but what they forgot to do is to migrate configuration.

Quote from [Spring Boot 1.4 release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#multipart-support):

> The multipart properties have moved from the `multipart.` namespace to the `spring.http.multipart.` namespace.

It means that obvious fix for you will be in modifying `application.properties` file.

Updated: I've filled issue for that: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files/issues/29

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I've since fixed the code and updated the code. Enjoy!

Comment: Ha! I had the opposite problem - using Boot 1.3.x with the 1.4 property names from the tutorial. :-)